# LLVM replace operand with function

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Using a LLVM pass, I wish to iterate through all conditional branches of the form `if(a==b)` and change these statements to `if(func(a)==func(b))` thereby replacing the original operands `a` and `b` with the result of function calls `func(a)` and `func(b)`. This should occur wherever an `if` statement of the form `if(a==b)` is found.

Here `a` is the operand. I can access this operand in my LLVM pass but I can't change it to be the result of a function. What approach should I use to achieve this.

It can be assumed that `a` and `b` are always of the same type and `func` takes in parameters of any type and returns the same type of the parameter. For simplicity it can also be assumed that `a` and `b` are integers and `func` returns an integer as well.

Comment: Replace them where? Are you asking if you can use a function as an argument? Please clarify.

Comment: The LLVM IR is in [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), you need to use [A-normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form)

Comment: Please don't comment your own question, but do **edit your question** to improve it (it needs *a lot* of improvement, and should be longer)

Comment: i've updated my question

Comment: What types are `a` and `b`? Are they always the same? Do you provide a `func` function for every type?

Comment: It is unclear where exactly the problem lies. By the current description, I'd assume it is the "change" of the operands. Well, you can't change them because of [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) form (as @BasileStarynkevitch mentioned). You need to insert the 2 function calls right before where the condition of the branch in question is evaluated (assuming a `icmp eq`) and **replace**  its operands with the return values of those calls.

Comment: @compor that's exactly what I want to do. Please point me in the right direction for replacing the operand with the return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Elaborating on my comment (although there are aspects that are still unclear)*

Adopting the following simplifications:

- that we are operating on integers
- the function to be called is defined already

we could do something like this in a `llvm::Function` pass:

```
bool runOnFunction(llvm::Function &CurFunc) override {
    bool hasChanged = false;

    // the llvm::Function to be called could be specified here
    auto *toCallFunc = [...];

    for (auto &bb : CurFunc) {
      auto *ti = bb.getTerminator();
      auto *bri = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::BranchInst>(ti);
      if (!bri)
        continue;
      if (!bri->isConditional())
        continue;

      auto *cond = bri->getCondition();

      // please note that this cast is for integer comparisons
      // adjust according to your needs
      auto cmpi = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::ICmpInst>(cond);
      if (!cmpi)
        continue;

      auto *opA = cmpi->getOperand(0);
      auto *opB = cmpi->getOperand(1);

      auto argsA = llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value *>(&opA, 1);
      auto argsB = llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value *>(&opB, 1);

      // note the insertion before the comparison operation
      auto *ciA = llvm::CallInst(toCallFunc, argsA, "funcA", cmpi);
      auto *ciB = llvm::CallInst(toCallFunc, argsB, "funcB", cmpi);

      cmpi->setOperand(1, opA);
      cmpi->setOperand(1, opB);
      hasChanged |= true;
    }

    return hasChanged;
  }
```

From then on, you can expand and deal with other argument types, depending on the required handling.